# Clause between comma

Tags: relative-clauses, comma-splices

> When the number of observations is even, say 2n, it is customary to define the median as the average of the nth and (n +1)st rank-ordered values.

The clause 'say 2n' between two comma appears to be grammatically wrong since it neither contains subject nor has reduced relative clause structure. What structure is this?

Comment: I'd say that "say 2n" is best analysed not as a clause, but as a PP meaning "for example 2n", functioning as a supplementary adjunct.

Comment: Parentheticals (like this) do not need to be clauses – they may be, of course.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the correct ways to express parenthetical comments?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/657/what-are-the-correct-ways-to-express-parenthetical-comments) Or this [parenthetical prepositional phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272576/parenthetical-prepositional-phrase) (the answer; the title is misleading).

Comment: Please note that how punctuate is not strictly a matter of grammar, even though it is a matter of English language usage.  Crazy as it may seem, you could put a comma after every word in the sentence, or use no no comma at all.  Either would be unhelpful to the reader and depart from the accepted norms of punctuation without being grammatically incorrect.  Note that in UK examinations at 16+ and 18+ there have at various times been marks awarded (or deducted) for "spelling, punctuation and grammar" (SPAG), recognising this difference.

Comment: The OP is not asking about punctuation, but the structure of the interpolation. As it happens, supplements are set apart by interpolation and _normally_ by punctuation, so their example is fine.